# transform-origin points out of viewbox

Tags: html, css, svg

Good night,

I have a SVG with a path in. This SVG has a viewBox to mantein the aspect ratio but the problem is that this figure (path) when it is going to be rotated the transform-origin (the point of rotation) is set to 0 point of the viewBox and not of the SVG. I want to rotate it with the point of rotation beeing the right corner or the left corner of the browser display (the the corner of thee SVG in my case, not the viewbox which is limitated when the dimensions changes). I try to do using groups and using all avaible units, cm,mm,pt,em,ex,px,... But all of then work in viewBox, and I dont see the difference between the relative and absolute units. I tryed the proportions (%) but not seems to work at least in firefox. And the same  with  center, right, left...

Anyway I dont think that units would fix the issue. There is something I´m not seeing.

Pd: It can be helped by JS or other scripting language.

Thanks you very much,

Answer (score 0):

How are you rotating the path?  Presumably you are using something like this?

```
<path d="..." transform="rotate(45)" />
```

This version of `rotate()` rotates about the current origin.  By default that is the top left (0,0) the document (not necessarily the top left of the viewBox).

To rotate around a different point, use the other version of rotate that takes angle ***and*** rotation origin:

```
<path d="..." transform="rotate(45, 150,150)" />
```